# Wrong tab in ViewPager capturing touch events

Tags: android

I have a ViewPager with several tabs (each their own fragment), each of which have their own clickable items. On most devices this works fine, but on some devices (so far, I've only seen it on an HTC Thunderbolt running 4.0.3 and a Samsung Galaxy S II running 4.0.4), all touch events are being captured by the tab (fragment) underneath (to the right of) the current tab. So, if I click a button or touch an EditText on (currently visible) fragment A, and there is a clickable button or EditText in the same place in fragment B (the next tab to the right), the clickable item in fragment B is what receives the touch event. Has anyone seen this before, and have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue and it took me very long to find the problem.

My problem was a custom PageTransformer for my ViewPager.
When i remove my PageTransformer everything works fine on all phones.

```
mViewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
```

Comment: I eventually figured out the same thing. Thanks for confirming!